# Redux forms doesn't use preloaded CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using MDBootstrap as my frontend CSS framework and redux forms for easy form control.

Problem that I have is that elements style/design is different from originally created in static html page.

This is original HTML static page design:

[image: Original static html example]

And this is result when using Redux forms Field component

[image: Redux form example]

I am not sure how and why this problem occurs. There is no error in console and all CSS/JS are loaded exactly same way:

Html static page assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://booking.dev/all-b46c73cdcb.css">
<script src="http://booking.dev/all-fad333e91d.js"></script>
```

Redux page assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://booking.dev/all-b46c73cdcb.css">
<script src="http://booking.dev/all-fad333e91d.js"></script>

<!-- redux/webpack JS -->

<script async="" src="http://booking.dev/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

And this is code i am using:

**Field componenet**

```
export const renderInput = field => {
return (
<div className= "col-md-4">
   <div className="md-form">
      <span className="prefix"><i className={field.icon}></i></span>
      <input
      {...field.input}
      type={field.type}
      className={`form-control ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.invalid ? 'invalid' : 'valid'}`}
      />
      <label id={field.input.name + 'Label'} htmlFor={field.input.name} className={field.meta.touched ? 'active' : ''} data-error={field.meta.error}
      data-success="">{field.label}
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
);


}
```

**Form section:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field} from 'redux-form'

import {renderInput} from '../../components/SingleInput'

export default class BookerInformation extends Component {

render() {
    return <div className="booker-form">
        <div className="thumbnail thumbnail-full cardbox booker-info">
            <div className="caption">
                <h4>Booker information</h4>
                <div className="row">
                    <Field name="fullName" classname="col-md-4" icon="icon-User" component={renderInput}
                           label="Full Name"/>
                    <Field name="phone" classname="col-md-4" component={renderInput} icon="icon-Phone"
                           label="Phone"/>

                </div>
                <div className="row">

                    <Field name="email" classname="col-md-4" component={renderInput} icon="icon-Email"
                           label="E-mail"/>
                </div>

                <div className="row text-center">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-continue waves-effect waves-light">Continue</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

Static html form element:

```
<div class="col-md-4">

   <div class="md-form">
      <span class="prefix"><i class="icon-User"></i></span>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control validate">
      <label for="name" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="">Full name</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the input background color is one of the differences. If you inspect one of your input elements, you should be able to see from which stylesheet the background color is applied from.

Comment: @Chris I checked and it loads totally different classes and I am not sure why...

Comment: I'm sure it does (otherwise it wouldn't look different). The question is from where? What file applies said styles?

Comment: @Chris It is a same file (all.css) but it uses different classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my error. I forgot to add `type` ( type="text")  to react fields which resulted incorrect styling. After adding correct type everything worked as it should.

Working Redux form field example:

```
 <Field name="fullName" classname="col-md-4" type="text" icon="icon-User" component={renderInput}
       label="Full Name"/>
```